# Is artificial intelligence investment more useful than human decision?

Tags: investment-strategies, automation

Many securities companies are promoting AI-powered investment products.
That is, artificial intelligence determines the proportion of products that they put their money on.
I wonder whether these products outperform human decisions on investment.

Comment: Apparently [a blindfolded money outperforms human investment decisions on average](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB991681622136214659) so unsurprising that AI might do it sometimes.

Comment: And now I'm visualizing a dollar bill with George Washington blindfolded. (Yes, I know, monkey not money.) ... Of course that's only one run of the test, and random results are just that, random. But it does illustrate how people can fool themselves into believing they have something better than random.

Answer (score 7):

There is no general answer possible. Which AI, applied where and how, operating on what inputs, matters far too much. AI by itself is a term that can mean almost anything.

However, the fact that index funds often outperform managed funds after fees are factored in, despite the fact that managed funds have been trying to leverage every bit of new technology that becomes available, strongly suggests to me that any claims to be able to reliably beat the market should still be viewed with extreme skepticism.

Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof.